# DbContext scope when calling a handler from another handler

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, dbcontext, mediatr

I have a fairly large application where one handler will call another handler. I have read how this is not something we should be doing:

- [Calling one handler from another one, is it good?](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/issues/434)
- [Dealing with Duplication in MediatR Handlers](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2016/12/12/dealing-with-duplication-in-mediatr-handlers/)
- [Can I send request using mediator in Application layer at other handler?](https://github.com/jasontaylordev/CleanArchitecture/issues/331)

However, refactoring the handlers so that we don't have them calling each other would be a large undertaking.

That being said, I would like to simplify a bit how handlers use Mediator to call the other handlers.

Here is an example of what a handlers would look like:

```
private readonly ISender _mediator;
private readonly UserHelper _userHelper;

public Handler(ISender mediator, UserHelper userHelper) {
  _mediator = mediator;
  _userHelper = userHelper;
}

public async Task<CreateUserResponse> Handle(CreateUserRequest request) {
      var response = await _mediator.Send(new CustomBizLogicRequest {
        OrgId = request.OrganizationId,
      });
 // ...
```

Using this approach works, but I would like to change it to use a helper class that would take care of using Mediator. Something like:

```
public class UserHelper {
  private readonly ISender _mediator;

  public UserHelper(ISender mediator) {
    _mediator = mediator;
  }

  public async Task<Result<CustomBizLogicResponse>> CustomBizLogicAsync(int orgId) =>
    await _mediator.Send(new CustomBizLogicRequest {
      OrgId = orgId,
    });
```

This way we could simplify the call from the `Handler` to use the injected `UserHelper:

```
      response = await _userHelper.CustomBizLogicAsync(request.OrganizationId);
```

When I try to use the helper method, I get:

> Cannot resolve
> 'MediatR.IRequestHandler`2[CustomBizLogicRequest,CustomBizLogicResponse]]'
> from root provider because it requires scoped service 'DbContext'.

The handler for `CustomBizLogic` expects `DbContext`, which I registered as:

```
services.AddDbContext<DbContext>(opt => {
  //...
});
```

I did find [this answer](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/issues/112) for a similar issue, but that one is a `BackgroundService`, instead of a web host, so I think the lifetime for `DbContext` would be different.

I'm confused why calling the hander from another handler using Mediator directly works, but moving the call to the helper class somehow changes the scope.

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/?force_isolation=true

Comment: Worth adding more code to the question, for example code which shows how `UserHelper` is created

Comment: As requested, I added code to show how `UserHelper` gets created, which is just constructor injection.

Answer (score 1):

The instance created over the DI has the same scope (IServiceProvider)

The one difference between a `BackgroundSerivce` and aspnet-controllers is that aspnet creates a new `ServiceScope` for every http-request, This `ServiceScope` is used to create the `Controller` instance itself and the DbContext too.

The result is that all services registered as `scoped` have the same lifetime as the http-request.

Because `DbContext` is a `Scoped` service, it requires not to be created from the `root` scope or else it would be effectively a singleton. `DbContext`  should be disposed/dereferenced after every process/usage/request.

For a `BackgroundService` and all other locations that require to create or get scopaed services from the DI or require to create new instances with DI support, need to create and dispose a new IServiceScope.

Create a new scope in the constructore or start method:

```cs
_scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope();
```

After you can request registered scoped services over it:

```cs
var ctx = _scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyDbContext>();
```

You can unregistred instances too:

```cs
var helper = ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<UserHelper>(_scope.ServiceProvider);
```

After the process or background services stops, dispose `_scope` and all scoped services including the **single** instance of `MyDbContext` will get disposed.